# What is this ring in this tree's bark?

Tags: trees, tree-care

There is a ring around about three quarters of this tree's trunk's circumference, about a foot tall. It looks like it was put there deliberately. What is the purpose of something like this?

[image]

Comment: This looks like *ringbarking*, a well known way to kill an unwanted tree.

Comment: Possibly from the removal of the bark because of engraved grafitti.

Comment: It looks to me like there's been a notice of some sort attached to the trunk in that area which had been there quite a while, and has since been removed.

Comment: The scratch marks and missing ridges look like someone went to work with a knife or froe, for who knows what reason.  At first I thought tree wrap was left on too long, but these seem to be scrape wounds, not compression wounds.